# Merging ASP.NET Identity DB with existing DB - how to deal with similar yet different tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have merged the existing database into an Identity database (created by the built-in MVC template with Individual User Accounts). Below you'll see a partial diagram.

[image: Partial Diagram]

I have added extra properties to the **AspNetUsers** table via code first approach.  All CRUD actions for this table are performed via the *ApplicationUserManager*.  My next planned step is to create an *Entity Framework* model using the database first approach and select only the non Identity tables. I'm having issues grasping the proper way to deal with the **AspNetUsers** and **People** table.

The **People** table will include users and non users. Most **AspNetUsers** will also have **People** entries, but not all **People** entries will be **AspNetUsers**.  The **People** table will have similar fields, not yet added, as the **AspNetUser** (Address, City, State, etc...).  Obviously this will create duplicate data.  What's a "best practice" way to do deal with this?  I considered adding an address table between them, but then I don't know how that would work with the *ApplicationUserManager* as it's only expecting the tables it created.

Comment: According to your relation rules you should add the extra fields only to People table and not to the AspNetUsers. If you add the same field to People table you will duplicate informations. A big no in SQL

Comment: @Steve - I thought about that and was hoping to find a way without rewriting the CRUD functions for the AspNetUser.